# Ecommerce combining UK US into one domain or separate, multitenancy?

Tags: seo, multi-tenant, api-design

I work for a smaller record label company that has distribution and office locations in the UK and US. They want to join the sites into one and use geoip to determine what content to show.

The UK has rights to show content that the US doesn't, orders in the US go to different distributors than the UK. Basically in almost every sense the functionality of the content is desired to work different. Licensing for example the UK uses different licensing with a third party and the US handles it themselves.

The stack plan was nodejs api as a central hub and SPA angular/javascript front end with an admin app under a sub domain.

Q1. I imagine for SEO it would be beneficial to have a .co.uk and .com domain instead of serving all from .com and changing content based on geoip?

Q2. I was originally planning to serve from a single API resource and return data attributed to different country/shops. But functionality wise there are different sections that use different functionality, such as licensing will function different in UK than it will US. Should the sites and data be independent, or should I try to make it work as a multitenant app and work through the different functionality based on the domain name? If I make a multitenant site it doesn't seem in areas of functionality that data will have the same structure.

Answer (score 1):

Are you building that site yourself? It's not sounding like a one man job to be honest. The correct solution sounds like you need to break the two sites apart, however if you're a 1 man team then that's a lot more work.

To do both sites with one infrastructure you'll need to abstract it in the correct way and probably put on it a few layers that will decorate and template it. I wouldn't advise that simply because node.js apps were meant to do a small functionality very well, and not become huge apps serving multiple domains.